# Changing 'term' in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete

I would like to have two different textboxes, autocomplete the second textbox based on the first textbox results.

For instance, in textbox 1 start typing "un" and all the countries that start with "un" will automatically appear, select united states, in the second textbox start typing "m" and only states within the united states that start with "m" will automatically appear.

My JS files:

```
var suggest = {
  instance : {}, // attached instances
  focus : null, // current text field in focus

  attach : function (opt) {
  // suggest.attach () : attach autosuggest to input field
  // opt : options
  //  - target : ID of target input field, required
  //  - url : Target URL to fetch suggestions, required
  //  - delay : Delay before autocomplete fires up, optional, default 500ms
  //  - min : Minimum characters to fire up autocomplete, default 2

    // Create autocomplete wrapper and box
    var id = Object.keys(suggest.instance).length,
        input = document.getElementById(opt.target);
    input.outerHTML = "<div id='acWrap" + id + "' class='acWrap'>" + input.outerHTML + "<div id='acBox" + id + "' class='acBox'></div></div>";

    // Set the HTML references and options
    suggest.instance[opt.target] = {
      input : document.getElementById(opt.target),
      wrap : document.getElementById("acWrap" + id),
      box : document.getElementById("acBox" + id),
      delay : opt.delay ? opt.delay : 500,
      url : opt.url,
      min : opt.min ? opt.min : 2,
      timer : null
    };

    // Attach key listener
    suggest.instance[opt.target].input.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
      // Clear old timer
      if (suggest.instance[opt.target].timer != null) {
        window.clearTimeout(suggest.instance[opt.target].timer);
      }

      // Hide and clear old suggestion box
      suggest.instance[opt.target].box.innerHTML = "";
      suggest.instance[opt.target].box.style.display = "none";

      // Create new timer, only if minimum characters
      if (evt.target.value.length >= suggest.instance[opt.target].min) {
        suggest.instance[opt.target].timer = setTimeout(
          function () { suggest.fetch(evt.target.id); },
          suggest.instance[opt.target].delay
        );
      }
    });

    // This is used to hide the suggestion box if the user navigates away
    suggest.instance[opt.target].input.addEventListener("focus", function (evt) {
      if (suggest.focus != null) { suggest.close(null, true); }
      suggest.focus = opt.target;
    });
  },

  fetch : function (id) {
  // suggest.fetch() : AJAX get suggestions and draw
  // id : ID of target input field, automatically passed in by keyup event

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(function (el) {
          suggest.instance[id].box.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div onclick=\"suggest.select('" + id + "', this);\">" + el + "</div>");
        });
        suggest.instance[id].box.style.display = "block";
        document.addEventListener("click", suggest.close);
      }
    });
    req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?term=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
    req.send();
  },

  select : function (id, el) {
  // suggest.select() : user selects a value from autocomplete

    suggest.instance[id].input.value = el.innerHTML;
    suggest.instance[id].box.innerHTML = "";
    suggest.instance[id].box.style.display = "none";
    document.removeEventListener("click", suggest.close);
  },

  close : function (evt, force) {
  // suggest.close() : close the autocomplete box if the user clicks away from the input field
  // evt : click event
  // force : force close

    if (force || event.target.closest(".acWrap") == null) {
      suggest.instance[suggest.focus].box.innerHTML = "";
      suggest.instance[suggest.focus].box.style.display = "none";
      document.removeEventListener("click", suggest.close);
    }
  }
};
```

I thought it would simple update the GET term

I created two different js files and updated the term line.

autocompletecountry.js

```
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?termco=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
```

autocompletestate.js

```
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?termst=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
```

My search.php files

```
<?php
// CONNECT TO DATABASE
$host = '11.22.33.44';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$charset = 'utf8';
$pdo = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset", $user, $password, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
  ]
);

// SEARCH AND OUTPUT RESULTS
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select distinct country FROM locationtbl WHERE country LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_GET['term'] . "%"]);
$data = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)) {
  $data[] = $row['country'];
}
$pdo = null;
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I created two different search files and updated the term line.

searchcountry.php

```
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_GET['termco'] . "%"]);
```

searchstate.php

```
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_GET['termst'] . "%"]);
```

Now what is happening is when I start typing in textbox 1 all countries are listed. however when I go to

```
example.com/searchcountry.php?termco=un
```

It will only show countries with 'un' in the name.

source: https://code-boxx.com/autocomplete-javascript-php-mysql/

My index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="autocompletecountry.js"></script>
    <script src="autocompletestate.js"></script>

    <script>
    /* [INIT - ON WINDOW LOAD] */
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
      suggest.attach({
        target : "inputA",
        url : "http://example.com/searchcountry.php"
      });
      suggest.attach({
        target : "inputB",
        url : "http://example.com/searchstate.php",
        delay : 200,
        min : 3
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" id="inputA"/>
     <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputB"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out what I had to do.

The page will only work properly with 1 autocomplete.js file

I had to edit the autocomplete.js like below

```
if (document.getElementById("inputB").value == '' && document.getElementById("inputC").value == '') {
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?term=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
req.send();
} else if (document.getElementById("inputC").value == '') {
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?cou=" + document.getElementById("inputA").value + "&term=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
req.send();
} else if (document.getElementById("inputA").value != '' && document.getElementById("inputB").value == '') {
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?cou=" + document.getElementById("inputA").value + "&term=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
req.send();
} else {
req.open("GET", suggest.instance[id].url + "?cou=" + document.getElementById("inputA").value + "&sta=" + document.getElementById("inputB").value + "&term=" + suggest.instance[id].input.value);
req.send();
}
},
```

This will allow for 3 autocomplete boxes reliant on the first textbox.